# Defining two children for a single link in URDF

Tags: ros, robotics, ros2, moveit, urdf

I am trying to create a URDF file for a robot model, namely Nimbro OP2X. I'm done with almost all parts, but when try to add two links for the lower leg and upper leg, a joint has to have two parents, which is according to my research, not possible in URDF file format.

So I added the links in the back, as "mimic" joint. But with that solution, I'm not able to use moveit utilities for inverse kinematics, since I cannot include those links in planning group. Is there a way to define it, or add them like normal joints in the urdf file without the use of mimic?

[While standing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzIEu.png)
[When the joint moves its not attached anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3rmH.png)